# Package does not exist - Apache AnT

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to build a project with Apache Ant. I am kinda new to Ant. I have 2 jars that have some classes that i need to include in my project. My build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="run" name="authentification user">
   <target name="run" depends="compile">
      <java classname="Authentification">
         <classpath path="staging" />
      </java>
   </target>
   <target name="compile">
      <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="staging" />
      <classpath>
         <pathelement path="lib/OASSoapWrapper-3.19.0-8778.jar" />
         <pathelement path="lib/OASSoapClient-3.19.0-8778.jar" />
      </classpath>
   </target>
</project>
```

My project directory structure is:

```
bin
src
lib
staging
build.xml
.classpath
.project
```

When I try to compile the build.xml with Ant I get "package does not exist error" but the package is in the jar files.

Comment: Please give the exact error output. *Which* package does supposedly not exist?! See [mcve] please.

Comment: None of the packages inside the jar files are found.Example: i have a package named AuthentificationBeam inside OASSoapWrapper-3.19.0-8778.jar file.

Comment: You need the classpath to be a child element of the javac task, otherwise javac isn't associated with that path, so doesn't use it.

Comment: And just a different note: using ANT yourself, that is like 2008 or so. If you learn things from scratch, consider using more modern technology, for example gradle.

Comment: Thanks,martin, this fixed the problem !